# Check if the right option value is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a problem checking a `select` that look like this:

```
<select name="recipe[category]"> 
<option value="-1">Yes</option> 
</select>
```

How can I check whether `-1` is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select the element and use the `val()` method to retrieve the selected value of the select element:

```
if ($("select[name='recipe[category]']").val() === "-1") {
    // -1 was picked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("select[name='recipe[category]']").val() == "-1")
{
     alert("You selected -1!");
}
```

I would suggest adding an id attribute to your select tag.  It is a lot faster for jquery to find tags based on ids

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($("select[name='recipe[category]'] option:selected").val() === "-1")) {
  //do someting
}
```